# Python, Subprocess call into a input field

Tags: python, subprocess

Im trying to change the password with python on a router with a linux OS.
The problem is im stuck in the input field which i've to complete with return.

My code looks like this:

```
root_password_bytes = subprocess.check_output(["pwgen", "-1", "32"])
root_password = root_password_bytes.decode('utf-8')

#root_password = subprocess.check_output(["pwgen", "-1", "32"])
#print(f'printing root passwd: {root_password}')

# Try 1: with decode and no quotation marks
subprocess.call([f"ssh root@192.168.1.1 printf {root_password}\n{root_password}\n | passwd"], shell=True)
# error: Syntax error: "|" unexpected

# Try 2: with decode and with quotation marks
subprocess.call([f"ssh root@192.168.1.1 printf '{root_password}\n{root_password}\n' | passwd"], shell=True)
# error: it tries to execute the command on my machine and not on the router

# Try 3: WITHOUT decode and no quotation marks
#subprocess.call([f"ssh root@192.168.1.1 printf {root_password}\n{root_password}\n | passwd"], shell=True)
# error: Syntax error: "|" unexpected

# Try 4: WITHOUT decode and with quotation marks
#subprocess.call([f"ssh root@192.168.1.1 printf '{root_password}\n{root_password}' | passwd"], shell=True)
# error: it tries to execute the command on my machine and not on the router
# passwd: Bearbeitungssfehler des Legitimierungszeichens

# Try 5: Without passwd as var
subprocess.call([f"ssh root@192.168.1.1 echo 'onetwothree\nonetwothree\n' | passwd"], shell=True)
# error: it tries to execute the command on my machine and not on the router
# passwd: Bearbeitungssfehler des Legitimierungszeichens
subprocess.call([f"ssh root@192.168.1.1 'printf onetwothree\n' | passwd"], shell=True)

# Try 6: different quotation marks most success it types the first password in
# but after using new-line (\n) the pipe will be unexpected
subprocess.call([f"ssh root@192.168.1.1 'printf onetwothree123 | passwd'"], shell=True)
# so this will not work
subprocess.call([f"ssh root@192.168.1.1 'printf onetwothree123\nonetwothree123\n | passwd'"], shell=True)
```

Answer (score 2):

You run 2 different and unrelated sub processes, they don't share input/output. You should either use [communicate()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.communicate) to send characters to the running process (also see examples at the bottom of the doc).

Or, you can modify the command to contain the password so you don't have to communicate with it: `ssh root@ip "echo 123 | passwd --stdin root"`

Comment: i have edited the code at the 1. post

Comment: you missed the `--stdin`, also notice the quotes `""` around the `echo | passwd`

Answer (score 0):

I now use the following solution

```
    root_password_bytes = subprocess.check_output(["pwgen", "-1", "32"])
    root_password = root_password_bytes.decode('utf-8')

    cmds = [
        f' rm -f /etc/dropbear/authorized_keys\n',
        f' printf "{root_password}{root_password}" | passwd\n',
        f' reboot'
    ]

    proc = subprocess.Popen(["ssh", "root@192.168.1.1"], stdin=subprocess.PIPE)
    for cmd in cmds:
        proc.stdin.write(f'{cmd}'.encode())
    proc.stdin.flush()
    proc.stdin.close()
    proc.wait()
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).